# column offset in bootstrap 3 is always on the right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

so I wanted to create a sidebar, then some space and the a content area. For the spacing between sidebar and content area, I wanted to use the .offset-*-* property from Bootstrap 3. But somehow, it doesn't work as excepted.

```css
.main-content {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container main-container">
      <div class="row">
          <!-- Sidebar -->
          <div class="sidebar col-md-3">
            sidebar
          </div>
          <!-- Main Content -->
          <div class="main-content col-md-8 offset-md-1">
            content
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

To see what I mean, run the example and swithc to Full Page Mode. As you see, the offset is at the most right instead being between the sidebar and the container. It also doesn't matter if I add it to the sidebar or the main-content element.

What's wrong with my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col-md-offset-1` instead of `offset-md-1` to the content div.

```css
.main-content {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container main-container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div class="sidebar col-md-3">
        sidebar
      </div>
      <!-- Main Content -->
      <div class="main-content col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ah, thanks. But can you maybe point out why .offset-md-1 doesn't work here?

Comment: @xotix Because as far as I know there is no such class like `offset-md-1`. to give offset you should use `col-md-offset-{no.}` class. If this answer helped to solve the issue you can mark It as answer by clicking the check box next to my answer